# Filling multiple boxes with block shapes

Tags: math

I need to fit a certain amount of block shapes with varying dimensions in a collection of available boxes as efficiently(least used boxes and wasted space) as possible. The shapes and boxes don't really align to any grid but if a grid helps, I would sacrifice some accuracy for better performance or simpler code.

This is for a product order system that should fit the ordered products in boxes in the most cost-effective way for shipping.

Comment: could you enlighten us what's the exact metric? "least used boxes and wasted space" is a bit vague.

Comment: First priority is reducing the number of boxes, since each box adds a fee to the shipment. Second priority is choosing as small boxes as possible without adding to the box count.

Comment: Then I will pick the biggest boxes :) Try to come up with a good metric, *then* you can start optimizing.

Comment: I accidentally hit enter and posted an incomplete comment before. The previous comment is now completely rewritten.

Comment: I came up with a less accurate system that seems to work for now. It's still in developement, so I can't really post working code or verfied methods yet. I'm still very interested in seeing different approaches to solving the _bin packing problem_, so I guess I'll leave this open and see what other people suggest :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is  a 2D bin packing problem. Depending on the size of The problem, optimal solution is probably not feasible.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem

There are a few different strategies to solve this suboptimally, see links from wiki article.

Comment: this is product shipping, so probably 3d packing ;)

Comment: I finally remembered to accept this answer. Sorry for the delay.